# How to extract the text content from multiple span elements using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to select text content from multiple DIV elements using selenium?

On the website I intend to collect information it contains div and span with the same class.

How can I collect this information separately?

I need the contents inside the panel-body div > span of each block

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='panel-body'][1]/span[1]").text
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='panel-body'][1]/span[2]").text
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='panel-body'][1]/span[3]").text

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='panel-body'][2]/span[1]").text
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='panel-body'][2]/span[2]").text
```

html

```
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Identificação</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="spanValorVerde">TEXT</span><br>
            <span style="font-size:small;color:gray">TEXT</span><br>
            <br>
            <span class="spanValorVerde">TEXT</span>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-success">

    
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Situação Atual</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="spanValorVerde">TEXT</span> <br>
            <span class="spanValorVerde">TEXT</span>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: I am expecting that "select text" meant "get text", if you search with findElements with ".//div[@class='panel-body'][i]" will give you the total element present, then add another loop for .//div[@class='panel-body'][i]/span[j] and then get text. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting that "select text" meant "get text".

first for loop:

```
count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='panel-body'][i]")
```

second for loop with `count` iteration:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='panel-body'][i]/span[j]").text
```

If you search with findElements with `".//div[@class='panel-body'][i]"` will give you the total element present, then add another loop for `.//div[@class='panel-body'][i]/span[j]` and then get text. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To extract the texts e.g. *TEXT*, from each `<span>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.panel.panel-success div.panel-body span.spanValorVerde")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='panel panel-success']//div[@class='panel-body']//span[@class='spanValorVerde']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)